# Get only one folder from a stream depot in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I am new to Perforce "stream depots" and stuck at step 1. I am trying to create a workspace that includes only one folder from a huge stream depot.

Every time I try, it seems to want to download the entire stream, which is a huge amount of files.  I can see no way to limit it to just one folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what virtual streams are for.

Create a new stream that is a child of the stream in question, with type "virtual", and specify its Paths as the single folder, e.g.:

```
Stream: //streams/just_the_facts
Parent: //streams/main
Type: virtual
Paths:
    share path/to/the/facts/...
```

Now switch to that stream:

```
p4 switch just_the_facts
```

and you only have the files from the `facts` folder.

Comment: Can the inner directory in the parent stream become the top directory in the virtual stream? So that in a workspace, instead of `path/to/the/facts` all the contents of the `facts` directory are right there in the workspace directory?

Comment: You should be able to do that with a `Remap`!

Comment: I found that I could _almost_ do it with a Remap: if I set the remap to `path/to/the/facts/... ./...` the checkout works, but then subsequent reconciles fail. I have settled for remapping `path/to/the/facts/... facts/...`

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was:

`p4 set P4CLIENT=MyWorkspace` then
`p4 client -s -S //My/Stream` to create the workspace.

Then `p4 sync //My/Stream/just/the/dir/I/want...`